# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/

Tags: python, django

I got the follwoing error whenever I run the project and automatically catalog/ is added to the url:

---

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/
Using the URLconf defined in first_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='index']
admin/
first_app/
The current path, catalog/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

---

Here is my project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('first_app/', include('first_app.urls')),

]
```

Here is first_app urls.py code:

```
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

How to get the index page as a default and get rid of the catalog.

Here is views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from first_app.models import Topic, AccessRecord, Webpage

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    webpages_list = AccessRecord.objects.order_by('date')
    date_dict = {'access_records': webpages_list}
    return render(request, 'first_app/index.html', context=date_dict)
```

Comment: The error is due you haven't defined a `path('catalog/')`, but it seems like that's not what you want. Can you share your views? You must be doing a redirection to that path

Comment: @revliscano, thanks for your reply. Yes, I have not defined catalog, but I did not write catalog with 127.0.0.0:8000, it comes automatically. OK,I'll add views to the question, thanks.

Comment: Everything seems correct. Haven't you installed any third-party library?

Comment: The problem started after I installed the "django-debug-toolbar". Later I uninstalled it but the problem not solved. Reinstalled complete anaconda and django but failed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Mak in your code u didnt mention any url related to /catalog/ so you are getting that 404 error message. Error 404 means that the page couldnt found by the server add /catalog/ in your url patterns so that the server could know which page is to be shown if /catalog/ is requested .  And as far as ur proble"and automatically catalog/ is added to the url:" may be its your browser autocompleting the address field so once plesase check it. if the request is only /catalog then ur myproject urls.py file should be something like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from first_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('first_app/', include('first_app.urls')),
    path('catalog',views.your_function_name)
]
```

if the request is first_app/catalog then ur first_app urls.py file should be something like this in url patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/catalog', views.catalog, name='catalog'),
]
```

Comment: Problem solved by clearing browser history and auto-completion, @Uday Kiran thanks a lot for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
     from django.contrib import admin
     from django.urls import path, include
     from first_app import views
     urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('first_app/', include('first_app.urls')),] 

   and

   from django.urls import path
   from first_app import views
   urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
   ]


    >>>>> if your templates files :
    templates/index.html



    def index(request):
    webpages_list = AccessRecord.objects.order_by('date')
    date_dict = {'access_records': webpages_list}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=date_dict)
```

Comment: the path off your files index.html !!?

Comment: path of index file is: templates/first_app/index.html

Comment: but sir ::  you dont have : http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/                                                                                                        
        urlpatterns = [
    path('/catalog', views.catalog, name='catalog'),
]

Comment: Or  2 eme solution >>>  you should test this :                                                                                                             
                     urlpatterns = [ path(' index/', views.index, name='index'), ]                                                       
                by      http://127.0.0.1:8000/index    >>>> index page

Comment: problem solved according to @Uday Kiran suggestion, thank you too, Stay blessed.